# eclipse code templates - indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation, code-templates

I have created a code template to add a logger and the corresponding import:

```
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

If I add this now, the logger always starts at the beginning of the line, even if my cursor is already indented. Is there a way to to force the placement at the position of the cursor?

This is a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

====>>>>

[image]

**Edit:** The answer from Grove helped in this specific case. But how about this example? I also want to add a comment to the logger. If I define the template like this in the same line, the logger actually apears in the same line as the comment.

```
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}
/**
 *  Logger
 */ private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Next time when you need additional details you can add comments to the answer, so people get notified. Modifying the question does not trigger notifications (unless maybe when you flagged it as a favourite?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to concentrate on templates for this. You can use **Formatter** for this.

Create your own formatter in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` and enable **Save Actions** in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions` (Select **Format Source code** and **Format all lines** options)  and here you choose your formatter created before.

Once you insert the logger template editor becomes dirty then save the editor(press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) then automatic indentation will happen as per the settings in formatter.

Refer [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-profile-to-format-java-code-in-eclipse.html) and [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse) for formatter creation. In **Indentation** tab use the number of space you like. I used `Tab Policy = Spaces only and Indentation size = 4`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, do not add a new line between the import and the logger definition:

```
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

Side-note: If needed, you can also position the cusrsor in your template with the `${cursor}` variable

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION UPDATE:** The same thing applies, the import variable does not have to be the first in the pattern, it can be anywhere and it will be evaluated nonetheless:

```
/**
 *  Logger
 */
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if any downvote would be accompanied by a short comment so I can figure out what I did wrong